# Can I apply for design patent whilst I have a utility application pending?

Tags: law, utility, design

I have filed an application for a utility patent. Can I also file for a design patent as a plan B should the application be denied?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Read for example this article for more background information: http://www.cdfslaw.com/publications/practice-tip-claiming-priority-design-utility-patent-applications/

Design and utility patents have different scopes of protection, so filing both might be a good idea even if the utility patent gets granted.

Comment: If possible, could I recommend you summarise the link in your answer to make it complete. This will ensure that future readers can still find this answer useful, even if the linked article changes.